# TortoiseSVN where put folder in repository

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to understand the workings of TortoiseSVN and I have a doubt about where to place the project in the repository.

I created a solution that has three projects in Vb.net (SolutionCalc)

I created a repository (Repo001)

When I do the import of SolutionCalc where should I put the Solution in the repository?

In https://code.aaa.bbb/svn/Repo001  or https:/code.aaa.bbb/svn/Repo001/trunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For on project in the repository I would recommend you

> https:/code.aaa.bbb/svn/Repo001/trunk

if there is more than one project in repository then:

> https:/code.aaa.bbb/svn/Repo001/**projectName**/trunk

In our projects we use ["stantdard-structure"](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/subversion_repo) with `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`. Works fine and new teammember who formally worked with svn understand the structure and "the way to use" quickly.

Comment: @Charles Bukowski: You're welcome and welcome to StackOverflow. Please feel free to use upvote and/or accepting function if my answer helps you.

Comment: How I must do for accepting function and what meaning?

Comment: @Charles Bukowski: If you find a answer helpful just click upvote (the arrow over the vote-number left to the question). If the answer is solution for you question check the hock under the vote-number. Of course you can combine both. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Comment: @Charles Bukowski: Thanks for accepting. +1 for that.